# C++ unexplained variations in template function matching with enums

Tags: c++, templates, enums, template-specialization, function-templates

I have the following code containing a template function. When I am calling this function with second parameter being an enum: in some cases it finds the  template specialization and in some cases it does not.

I had verified that enums are the same enums in both cases (e.g there are no redefinitions) and that other parameters have correct values, I found that one compilation is done with -Winline set (I did not try changing it yet) what else to look at?

```
class A {
public:
    template <typename T>
    int f(uint32_t id, T const& t, bool cond);

    ...
};

template <typename T>
int A::f(uint32_t id, T const& t, bool cond)
{
   ...
}

template <>
inline int A::f<int>(uint32_t, int const& t, bool cond)
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to specialize a function template outside its class without declaring the specialization within the class?

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock- Yes, this is legal.  You are only allowed to fully specialize it, though.  I have no idea why the standards committee decided to make this legal.

Comment: @templatetypedef: that is really odd.  Did you undo the fixes I put into the code (the signature to the specialization, in particular)?

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock- If I did it wasn't intentional.  Did you have any fixes other than the ::?

Comment: `A:f<int>` -> `A::f<int>` and `boo` -> `bool` are the two I saw.

Comment: @zzz777: could you demonstrate in which situation the specialization is called/not called ? I see no reason that the `int` overload should be preferred for an `enum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, typically, it's inadvisable to use template specialization as a way of overloading a template function.  Template specializations interact poorly with function overloading and have some pretty arcane rules dictating when they're chosen, and in general it's considered better to just provide a regular function overload than to specialize a function template.

In this case, I'd advise changing your class to look like this:

```
class A {
public:
    template <typename T>
        int f(uint32_t id, T const& t, bool cond);
    int f(uint32_t id, int t, bool cond);
    ...
};
```

Then changing your template specialization to just be an implementation of the overload.  Due to the way that C++ function overloading works, this will select the correct version of the function more accurately.

As for your particular question, the reason that your code isn't always calling the overload is that C++ makes a distinction between an enumerated type and the type `int`.  Though there are ways of converting between `int`s and enumerated types, they aren't the same thing, and an overload designed to catch `int`s is not guaranteed to catch enumerated types as well.  You are probably better off specifically overloading the function to handle the enumerated case.

Comment: Great that you've an alternative/workaround, but the rationale for recommending it is basically FUD.

Comment: +1 I agree, mixing integers and enums in overloads and/or specializations is tricky to say the least. In my book, that's labelled with the evil words: "undefined behaviour".

Comment: @Mikael: there's a big difference between saying "hey, the Standard says this is Undefined Behaviour - don't do it", and "yikes - this is just too trivial, you can't trust the current generation - or this particular - compiler to follow the Standard".  Would be nice to know which category we're talking about, or if there's simply some other flaw in the failing code (the code I've posted didn't reproduce the problem under GCC).

Comment: @Tony- The reason to avoid function template specialization is that it interacts poorly with overloading and can lead to completely counterintuitive results.  See http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm for some more rationale.  Thanks for pointing out that I was being vague; hopefully this is a more useful explanation.  And @Mikael Persson- it's not undefined behavior; it's just weird. :-)

Comment: Man, don't you guys know the meaning of "in my book", it's an expression, it means "in my opinion"... geez.. I wasn't referring to an actual book! And definitely not the C++ standard!

Comment: @templatetypedef: that's one scenario in which to beware and/or avoid this, but it's of no relevance to this specific question and still sheds no light on why the posted code - which doesn't appear to have any relevant overloads - didn't perform as expected.

Comment: @Tony- Ah, I see.  I attempted to answer this in the last paragraph.  C++ treats enums and ints differently, and so a specialization designed to match ints won't match an argument of an enumerated type.

Comment: @templatetypedef: the point is that an `enum` is a different type, and is not an `int`, so the general template should always be used and the `int` specialisation never... how can you account for zzz777's reported behaviour that the `int` specialisation is sometimes used? Your last paragraph boils down to "well, it might be", but provides no insight.  You speak of "ways of converting", but when and why would that be attempted if the argument is one of the `enum` values?

Comment: @Tony- You're correct.  I see no reason why it should ever get called at all.  Looking over the spec, I can't see any reason that the compiler would pick the specialized version in some cases and not others.  Perhaps it's a compiler bug where the compiler is using ints to represent the enum, and is getting confused into thinking the enum really is an int?  I have no idea, though.

Comment: @templatetypedef: that's where I'm at with this too... suspecting a compiler bug... that's why I specifically tried forcing an int-sized enum by having INT_MIN and INT_MAX values and checking sizeof, but GCC 3.4.6 is still smart enough to treat the enum as a different type.  Would help if zzz777 contributed his compiler information and complete code demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not an attempted answer, but want to post more than will fit in a comment...

Basically, this shows expected behaviour (enums never matching int specialisation) for GCC 3.4.6.  What compiler are you using?  Can you actually provide a similar, complete program that produces the error?

```
#include <iostream>                                                             

struct A                                                                        
{                                                                               
  public:                                                                       
    template <typename T>                                                       
    void f(const T&) { std::cout << "general\n"; }                              
};                                                                              

template <>                                                                     
void A::f<int>(const int&) { std::cout << "specialised\n"; }                    

enum E1 { Zero, One, Two };                                                     

enum E2 { Max = INT_MAX };                                                      

int main()                                                                      
{                                                                               
    A a;                                                                        
    a.f("abc");                                                                 
    a.f(123);                                                                   
    a.f(Zero);                                                                  
    E1 e = Two;                                                                 
    a.f(e);                                                                     
    a.f(Max);                                                                   
}
```

Output:

```
general
specialised
general
general
general
```